# How mock a method two times with different lambda expression?

Tags: c#, lambda, mocking, repository, moq

I have a manager (business layer) which calls a repository (Data access layer with EF).
The logic of the manager will call two times a method of the repository with two different lambda expressions as parameter.

My question is how to mock my repository to return a given response for a first lambda, but return another response for a second lambda?

For example:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Relation
{
    public int GiverId { get; set; }
    public int ReceiverId { get; set; }
}

public interface IRelationRepository
{
    bool Loves(Expression<Func<Relation, bool>> predicate);
}

public class RelationRepository : IRelationRepository
{
    public bool Loves(Expression<Func<Relation, bool>> predicate)
    {
        // Some logic...
        return true;
    }
}

public class KissManager
{
    private readonly IRelationRepository repository;

    public KissManager(IRelationRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public bool Kiss(Person p1, Person p2)
    {
        var result = this.repository.Loves(r => r.GiverId == p1.Id && r.ReceiverId == p2.Id)
            && this.repository.Loves(r => r.GiverId == p2.Id && r.ReceiverId == p1.Id);
        return result;
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void KissWithReceiverNotInLove()
{
    // Arange.
    var p1 = new Person { Id = 5, Name = "M. Love" };
    var p2 = new Person { Id = 17, Name = "Paul Atreid" };

    var kissRepositoryMock = new Mock<IRelationRepository>();
    kissRepositoryMock
        .Setup(m => m.Loves(r => r.GiverId == p1.Id && r.ReceiverId == p2.Id))
        .Returns(true);
    kissRepositoryMock
        .Setup(m => m.Loves(r => r.GiverId == p2.Id && r.ReceiverId == p1.Id))
        .Returns(false);

    var kissManager = new KissManager(kissRepositoryMock.Object);

    // Act.
    var result = kissManager.Kiss(p1, p2);

    // Assert.
    Assert.IsFalse(result);
}
```

Comment: [SetupSequence](https://codecontracts.info/2011/07/28/moq-setupsequence-is-great-for-mocking/) instead of `Setup`. Make sure you set them up in the right order, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works !
But if I change the order of my calls (in the manager), it change nothing functionally but my test will failed. Do you know another way?

Comment: The order of SetupSequence will have to match what is in the SUT. If you change the order of the calls in your SUT, then you're test will have to be updated. The tests will be brittle in this regard.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll keep it like that and post my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to Setup the method to accept any expression/predicate via `It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Relation, bool>>>()` and use a fake data source that allows the desired behavior with a given predicate/expression.

```
[TestMethod]
public void _KissWithReceiverNotInLove() {
    // Arange.
    var p1 = new Person { Id = 5, Name = "M. Love" };
    var p2 = new Person { Id = 17, Name = "Paul Atreid" };
    var relations = new List<Relation>()
    {
        new Relation{ GiverId = p1.Id, ReceiverId = p2.Id }
        //The above should satisfy the first expected predicate.
        //Note there are no other relations in this list.
        //That is by design to make the second predicate return false.
    };

    var kissRepositoryMock = new Mock<IRelationRepository>();

    kissRepositoryMock
        .Setup(m => m.Loves(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Relation, bool>>>()))
        .Returns((Expression<Func<Relation, bool>> predicate) => relations.Any(predicate.Compile()));

    var kissManager = new KissManager(kissRepositoryMock.Object);

    // Act.
    var result = kissManager.Kiss(p1, p2);

    // Assert.
    Assert.IsFalse(result);
}
```

Comment: It is a very good way to simulate the dataset on the repository. Thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

As it is said in the comment of the first post, it is also possible to use SetupSequence, but I prefer @Nkosi solution because it is not depending of implementation.

I post an example of SetupSequence usage in our example. It can be usefull for somebody.

```
[TestMethod]
public void KissWithReceiverNotInLove()
{
    // Arange.
    var p1 = new Person { Id = 5, Name = "M. Love" };
    var p2 = new Person { Id = 17, Name = "Paul Atreid" };

    var kissRepositoryMock = new Mock<IRelationRepository>();
    kissRepositoryMock
        .SetupSequence(m => m.Loves(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Relation, bool>>>()))
        .Returns(true)
        .Returns(false);

    var kissManager = new KissManager(kissRepositoryMock.Object);

    // Act.
    var result = kissManager.Kiss(p1, p2);

    // Assert.
    Assert.IsFalse(result);
}
```